# How to find and list all the symbolic links created for a particular file?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

I had created many symbolic links on various paths for a particular file or a directory. I want the whole list of created symbolic links paths (location).

#### Example:

I created symbolic links for `~/Pictures` directory on many directories. How do I list all the symlinks to that `~/Pictures` directory?

Is that possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: You need to search exhaustive, there is no count stored like there is for hard-links. See one of the answers using find.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
find -L /dir/to/start -xtype l -samefile ~/Pictures
```

or, maybe better:

```
find -L /dir/to/start -xtype l -samefile ~/Pictures 2>/dev/null
```

to get rid of some errors like `Permission denied`, `Too many levels of symbolic links`, or `File system loop detected` which `find` throws them when doesn't have the right permissions or other situations.

- `-L` - Follow symbolic links.
- `-xtype l` - File is symbolic link
- `-samefile name` - File refers to the same inode as `name`. When `-L` is  in  effect, this can include symbolic links.

**Notes:**

- Use lowercase L in `-xtype l`, not the digit 1.
- On macOS / Darwin, `-xtype` is `-type`.

Comment: Could the command be modified to find symbolic link that contains a path? e.g. files across the system that may link to ~/Pictures/A, ~/Pictures/A/B/C, or any files in the subdirectories of ~/Pictures>

Answer (score 8):

Very simple, use option `-lname`:

```
find / -lname /path/to/original/dir
```

From `man find`:

```
-lname pattern
       File is a symbolic link whose contents match shell pattern pattern.  The
       metacharacters do not treat `/' or `.' specially.  If the -L option or the
       -follow option is in effect, this test returns false unless the symbolic link
       is broken.
```

**Note**: Remember that symbolic links could be anywhere, which includes a remote system (if  you’re sharing files), so you may not be able to locate them all.

Comment: Note also, if the symlink is a relative path like `../dir` then it won't find the absolute `/path/to/original/dir` you can instead use a pattern and weed out false positives `-lname \*dir`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ls -i ~/

277566 Pictures
```

`find . -follow -inum 277566` ( find directories with the same **inode** number )

It will display all its symbolic links paths .

Comment: This will find hard links, not symbolic links. Hard links share inode numbers. symbolic links have different inode numbers. the inode of a symbolic link has a path instead of a block list.

Comment: the question didn't mention hard or soft symbolic link

Answer (score 0):

I like this one-liner the most:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec readlink -f '{}' \;`

refs:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22128/how-to-get-full-path-of-original-file-of-a-soft-symbolic-link

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21984/list-symlinks-in-current-directory