# how to find symbolic link for a specific file

Tags: symbolic-link

i want to know how to find if a certain file has a symbolic link to another file?

the LN command

```
# ln -s /etc/kannel.conf /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

how to confirm this symbolic link?

Comment: Something like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/429247/how-to-find-and-list-all-the-symbolic-links-created-for-a-particular-file ?

Comment: What do you mean confirm it? If you know the name of the link, `ls -l /etc/kannel/kannel.conf` will show you if it exists and what it links to. Finding all links to a target when you only know the target is a different question, which one do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use `test` command.

```
pastas@ubuntan:~/tmp$ ls -alth
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 2 pastas pastas 4.0K Dec 16 17:18 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pastas pastas    9 Dec 14 18:34 robot.cpp_2 -> robot.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pastas pastas  106 Dec 14 16:13 robot.cpp
pastas@ubuntan:~/tmp$ test -L robot.cpp_2 && echo "sym" || echo "not sym"
sym
pastas@ubuntan:~/tmp$ test -L robot.cpp && echo "sym" || echo "not sym"
not sym
```